# How to connect superset with mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I was trying to connect superset with mysql database with this SQLAlchemy URI:`mysql://localhost:3306/mysql/database/table1`  but not able to connect.

I was getting this error:

```
ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!

The error message returned was:
No module named 'MySQLdb'", "stacktrace": "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/Users/akay/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset/views/core.py\", line 1703, in testconn
    engine = database.get_sqla_engine(user_name=username)
  File \"/Users/akay/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset/utils/core.py\", line 131, in __call__
    value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"/Users/akay/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset/models/core.py\", line 923, in get_sqla_engine
    return create_engine(url, **params)
  File \"/Users/akay/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py\", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"/Users/akay/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py\", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File \"/Users/arkay/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py\", line 118, in dbapi
    return __import__(\"MySQLdb\")
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
"}
```

Is there any way to connect to a MySQL database?

Answer (score 8):

MySQLdb is not compatible with Python 3, You need to use pymysql.

**Install pymysql:**

```sh
$ pip install pymysql
```

Connect to mysql data source with below URI string.

```
mysql+pymysql://user:pass@host/databasename
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your database user with hostname=localhost

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `mysql-connector-python` module:

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similiar issue. I'm sure this will save time for some of you out there:

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Here is the perfect template for MySQL string:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/schema-name'
```

Install MySQL:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Upgrade SQLAlchemy:

```
pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24
```

Load DB:

```
superset db upgrade
```

Create Admin user:

```
superset fab create-admin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker try using **host.docker.internal** as host name. It worked for me